# Chrome: Zoom is not working in child tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have an unusual behavior in Google Chrome when I open new tab using `window.open()` function. 
The zooming on child tab is not working...

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/822rj8nr/)

Does anybody knows the workaround for this? 
Thank you

Comment: Interesting, I can see the same behavior. :-) It works in Firefox as expected. I believe it's because you write to the window with JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$("#openWndBtn").click(function() {
  var wnd = window.open("about:blank", "opa");
  wnd.document.body.innerHTML = "test";
});
```

However, I don't know why your script leads to non-zoomable page. I believe it's a Chrome's bug.